# Do I need to have an == true in an if statement when the part in parenthesis is an awaited DisplayAlert?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Here's the code I have:

```
if (await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert($"Stop Quiz {Settings.Quiz}", $"{Environment.NewLine}Please confirm{Environment.NewLine}", "OK", "Cancel") == true)
{
   StopQuiz();
}
else
{
   App.showCard = STATUS.Running;
}
```

Is that the correct way to do this with the "await" and also do I still need to check `== true`?

Comment: I assume it's because `DisplayAlert` returns a `bool?` (i.e. a nullable `bool`)? Nothing to do with the `await`

Comment: What does `DisplayAlert` returns? if `Nullable<bool>`, than yes, you have to check or use `HasValue` property

Comment: What happens when you modify the code and test it?

Comment: What do you mean use the HasValue? Can you give an example? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current section Shell.Current.DisplayAlert returns you non nullable bool, so calling

```
if (await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert($"Stop Quiz {Settings.Quiz}", $"{Environment.NewLine}Please confirm{Environment.NewLine}", "OK", "Cancel"))
{
   StopQuiz();
}
else
{
   App.showCard = STATUS.Running;
}
```

Will work just fine.

Look for more details in [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.page.displayalert?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Xamarin.Forms.Page.DisplayAlert);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=xamarin-forms)

Edit : actual method declaration is

> public System.Threading.Tasks.Task< bool> DisplayAlert (string title,
>   string message, string accept, string cancel);

so it means it is awaitable Task < T> that will need to be awaited.